# If statement not functioning for password

Tags: python

I've been having a problem, i have some code to start off a menu system thing I've been doing, and no matter if the username and password are correct, it simply will not register them being equal?

```
def passw():
  f=open("userpass.txt","r")
  a=linecache.getline('userpass.txt',1)
  a=str(a)
  c=linecache.getline('userpass.txt',2)
  c=str(c)
  f.close()
  print(a+c)
  if a == "" and c == "":
    f=open("userpass.txt","a")
    user=input("Please enter a username: ")
    f.write(user)
    f.write("\n")
    password=input("Please enter a password: ")
    f.write(password)
    f.close()
    menumain()
  elif a != ""  and c != "":
    f=open("userpass.txt","r")
    user=linecache.getline('userpass.txt',1)
    user=str(user)
    user=user[0:-1]
    rpass=linecache.getline('userpass.txt',2)
    rpass=str(rpass)
    print(user,rpass)
    f.close()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    while True:
      inputUser = str(input("Enter your username: "))
      inputPass = str(input("Enter your password: "))
      if inputUser == user and inputPass == rpass:
        menumain()
      else:
        print("Incorrect username or password")
```

Comment: What is the first `f=open("userpass.txt", "r")` for?

Comment: you don't need to open the file if you're reading it with `linecache`.

Comment: You're only checking if the username and password they entered matches the first username in the `userpass.txt` file. You need to loop through the entire file.

Comment: The `if` statement does activate if file does not contain passwords. But I cannot further debug the program without `menumain()`.

Comment: I see, but that didn't fix the problem